# Why does the remove() method change a list it is not written on?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
rep_list = ['A', 'B']
no_rep_list = rep_list
for repeat in rep_list:
    for repeat2 in rep_list:
        print(repeat, repeat2)
        no_rep_list.remove(repeat)
```

Now I found that this code prints only:

```
A A
```

instead of:

```
A A

A B

B A

B B
```

Meaning that the remove() method change the for loops. And when printing the rep_list at the end, I found it changed it to ['B'] while it is (the remove method) not even written on the rep_list.

Does anyone know why the remove() method behave like this? I thought it only removes the element in its argument from the list it is written on.

Comment: `no_rep_list = rep_list` doesn't make a copy, just a new reference to

Comment: `no_rep_list` and `rep_list` **are**  the same list, just by two different names. That's how variables and references work.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: Dropping by to mention that if you do not want this behaviour you will have to [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

Comment: @ItayLevi Few examples to copy a list: `import copy`, `no_rep_list = copy.copy(rep_list)` or for a 100% copy: `no_rep_list = copy.deepcopy(rep_list)`. List comprehension: `no_rep_list = [x for x in rep_list]`